# Asp.Net WebForms - How to pass ViewData as param to User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am new to ASP.net and have inherited an app to update.  I'm going quite well though have struck a situation I need some help understanding.

I have a user control `uc:speciesgrid` that takes some arguments:  `applicationId` and `species` should be from ViewData and passed as arguments, however I cannot find a syntax that works.  A hardcoded call to it (that works) is:

```
<uc:speciesgrid runat="server" ID="speciesgrid1" applicationId="6191" species="Dog"/>
```

I tried all combinations of `<%, <%=, <%#` and none will work.  So something like:

```
<uc:speciesgrid runat="server" ID="speciesgrid1" applicationId='<%AppData["NoiId"]%>' species="Dog"/>
```

The errors are all the same:

`{"Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representa{ion 'ViewData[\"NoiId\"]' for the 'applicationId' property."}`

It is obvious that whatever I've included is being interpreted literally rather than having the server substitute in the value.

I also tried setting a variable and using that but the error is the same.

```
<%
var applicationId = ViewData["NoiId"];
%>
```

What IS working is accessing `ViewData['NoiId']` in the User Controller:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Debug.WriteLine("In the controller, ViewData['NoiId'] is: " + ViewData["NoiId"]);
}

> In the controller, ViewData['NoiId'] is: 6191
```

It would seem to me that:

- User Controls are built initialy on the server "before" that application starts.  Hence why I can't pass any `<%` arguments.
- And to pass arguments the only way is through `ViewData` and similar mechanisms that are interpreted later in the life cycle "at run time".

However I'd prefer pass arguments as parameters if at all possible.

Is it possible?  Or is my understanding in that paragraph 2 above correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use `MVC` pattern in ASP.NET and you tend to pass parameter from `View` to `UserControl`. For do it, you can not use code below in view page:

```
<uc:speciesgrid runat="server" ID="speciesgrid1" applicationId="6191" species="Dog"/>
```

Because view page has not code behind. For pass parameter to `UserControl`, you can use this code:

```
<% Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/SpeciesGridController.ascx", ViewData["NoiId"]); %>
```

`Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial` used for load `ascx` or `Partial View` in `ASP.NET MVC`. Then you can get `ViewData["NoiId"]` and set this to variable or property of `ascx` in `Page_Load` like this:

[image: UserControl]

Comment: Yes thanks Ali that is what I worked out.  I asked this same question but more precisely in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168566/asp-net-c-sharp-generate-user-control-parameters/46210657#46210657 and provided an answer along these lines.